# Icon next to text/span appears in the next line on mouse hover

Tags: html, css

I need to show an edit icon next to the text (inline), when user hovers mouse over it. When i hover over the text, the edit icon is falling in the next line.

My span is taking up the 100% of div width, even though i have set it to 80% width and the rest 20% width is reserved for the right side icon.

Span style is,

```
span{
display: inline-block;max-width:80%;width:80%;
}
```

It looks like,

[image]

How can i display the icon inline, at the right end in the same line as the text? 
Plunker code is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/whqttI7DAThlmZEtOLKW?p=preview).

Comment: you want to display `inline`?

Comment: yes.,,,, i am setting the display for span as `inline-block`

Comment: but your text so long, then you set the `cntr` for 20% only,

Comment: Do you want to display the icon on top of the text?

Comment: i need to display the icon inline, at the right end in the same line as the text

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this.

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
     console.log('document ready callback fn is invoked')
     $('.menu-body').hide()
   })
   $('body').on('click', '.drp-down-btn', function(){
     $('.menu-body').toggle()
   })
```

```css
.cntr{
   width: 20%;
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
   display: block;
 }
 .cntr  i {
   visibility: hidden;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: all 0.4s;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
   cursor: pointer;
 }

<!-- .cntr:hover{
   border: solid black 1px;
 } -->
 .cntr:hover > i{
      display: inline-block;
 }
 .cntr>span>p{
   width: 15%;
   overflow:hidden;
   vertical-align:middle;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
 }
.cntr span,.cntr p,.cntr i{
    display: inline-block;
}
 .cntr:hover  i{
   visibility: visible;
   opacity: 1;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="cntr">
    <span>
      <p>Hello worldaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
      <i class="fa fa-edit fa-lg" style="padding-left:5px;border-left: solid black 1px;">
      </i>
      </span>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`span` is inline element by default and you cannot add width to it unless you display it as block.

```html
<div>
  <span style="display:inline-block; width:80%;">Hello Hello Hello</span>
  <i style="display:inline-block; padding-left:5px;float: right;   border-left: solid black 1px; width: 15%;">ICON</i>
</div>
```

Comment: i had added a width to the span element with its style as`display:inline-block`. the problem comes, when the width of container is less say 20 per cent and your span text is long enough to take all of that space, leaving no space for icon element...